# How to fix "IndexError: list index out of range"?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am scraping a directory with python 3 scrapy.
The data scraped is added in a Mysql database throught pipelines.py

I get this error message "IndexError: list index out of range" very often.

For this question, it happen when I scraped the url of a link. Sometimes the directory publish the website of the item, sometimes not.

I didn't find any solutions on stackoverflows.
I tried to convert in string but it doesn't work.

this is the line of code which create this error:

```
items['startup_website'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='listing-detail- section-content-wrapper']//a/@href")[0].get() or ''
```

Does anyone knows how can I fix this error?

Comment: I can't give you the correct answer without seeing what you are scraping. But the error `IndexError` means you are trying to access an invalid position in a list. This statement `response.xpath("//div[@class='listing-detail- section-content-wrapper']//a/@href")` probably returns `[]` sometimes and you are trying to access the position [0], which does not exist. You can try to check if the xpath query is empty before trying to access its values, or simple get rid of the `[0]`, the `get()` will already return the first occurrence.

Answer (score 3):

The indexing is unnecesary; you should skip it altogether.

[`.xpath()`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.xpath) returns a `SelectorList`, which has a [`.get()`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.SelectorList.get) method of its own.
Using this will get you the wanted result:

```
>>> fetch('http://example.com')
2019-08-14 14:28:03 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://example.com> (referer: None)
>>> response.xpath('//a/@href').get('')
'http://www.iana.org/domains/example'
>>> response.xpath('//fake/a/@href').get('')
''
```

Comment: Thank you @stranac & Michael Savchenko for your help. My example was bad. It happens sometimes I need to extract the 2nd, 3rd? index. For example if I need to extract the 2nd <td> of a <table>, I need to use these [index]. I am often having this issue. What do you do usually in this kind of issue?

Answer (score 1):

`[0]` is excessive here.
use `response.xpath("//selector").get() or ''`